# Visual studio code snippets for Javascript inside .php files

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I've got two debug snippets, one for PHP, one for Javascript.
I use the same keyboard binding:

```js
{
  "key": "ctrl+D",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'php'",
  "args": {
    "langId": "php",
    "name": "Debug output for PHP"
  }
}, {
  "key": "ctrl+D",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'javascript'",
  "args": {
    "langId": "javascript",
    "name": "Debug output for Javascript"
  }
},
```

Everything is fine, when I work with a .php file with PHP code or a .js file with JS code.
But if I work with the JavaScript code inside PHP, it uses PHP variant, because the file language is PHP.
PHP files can include PHP, JS or HTML blocks, but, as I see, the `editorLangId` parameter of `when` don't recognize it.
Is there any way to refine a condition for language, to detect a "context" language?

Comment: Out of the box? I believe not. If you want to write a code which will identify that, you can try to use [`php-parser`](https://github.com/glayzzle/php-parser.glayzzle.com/) to identify if the cursor is now inside a script tag. You can get an idea by playing with it - https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0a6cbfb5d8b2bba34450928fff21c32d/66cd4c98359a61a4d42a68b0692f66f81b33b710